# Synchronizing RPU timer with gPTP clock on Xilinx UltraScale+

Tags: embedded-linux, fpga, xilinx

I'm working on an application that involves Xilinx UltraScale+ SoC, where the APU runs Linux and the system clock is synchronized with the gPTP (Generalized Precision Time Protocol) clock. My goal is to run a software application on the RPU (Real-Time Processing Unit) side that needs to be in sync with the gPTP clock. Is there a way to synchronize the RPU timer with the gPTP clock? or just access the gPTP clock from the APU in the RPU?